# Python/Django EmailMultiAlternatives send multiple emails

Tags: python, django, email

i want to send multiple emails in a view.
what i need is, that view sends the responcse back and send emails in the background.

when i run

```
return EmailMultiAlternatives(subject,
                             t,
                             sender,
                             recipients,
                             bcc=bcc).send()
```

the view does not send the response until it sends an email or two or whatever.

i want to ask why

```
    yield EmailMultiAlternatives(subject,
                             t,
                             sender,
                             recipients,
                             bcc=bcc).send()
```

instruction not send my email??
why yield is not behaving like i want it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django framework (unlike [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/), or [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/)) works in a synchronous/blocking mode, the view won't return you the response until it did everything.

If you don't want to wait for emails to be sent, you should take a look at [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) and [django-celery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery) packages. Define a task, put it on a queue from the view, return the response and let the worker do the job "in the background".

Also, see:

- [Python/Django: sending emails in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7626071/python-django-sending-emails-in-the-background)
- [Asynchronously sending email using Django, Celery, Django-mailer](http://iambusychangingtheworld.blogspot.ru/2013/04/asynchronously-sending-email-using.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. i am looking at them now.

Comment: Yes!, Celery is great, but as well you can just make AJAX requests to send mails what is simpler. Just make a url for sending e-mail and view where you will actually send mail and send simple response which you can show in html.

Comment: like in python Scrapy framework, the callback method can yield any request.